# Excel Dynamic Range like concatenate, calculated row

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How do i find ranges in excel
i want to make dynamic ranges based on my current row position.
i've already tried below code

`=SUMIF(B5:B(ROW()-1), "<> ", E5:E(ROW()-1))`

Comment: according to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d , row() returns the current position. So what you want to do corresponds with the current position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX is likely your best bet.

```
=SUMIF(B$5:index(B:B, ROW()-1), "<>", E$5:index(E:E, ROW()-1))
```

Comment: Would you need B$5, E$5 to anchor it to the first cell in the range ?

Comment: That's a good point @TomSharpe and I'll [edit] to suit. I was following the op's original but that should improve versatility.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to put the formula

```
=SUMIF(B$5:B5,"<> ", E$5:E5)
```

In the column you are interested in on row 6 and then copy down the column.